# Feature selection in python

Tags: python, scikit-learn, feature-selection

I am trying to perform feature selection in python using several techniques. The first technique that I am trying to apply is selecting features using only the varience of the features. My code is the following:

```
def feature_selection_technique(train, test, lbls, technique):
   if technique == "variance":
        sel = VarianceThreshold(threshold=(0.00010 * (1 - .15)))
        model1 = sel1.fit_transform(face_train)
        new_train = model1.transform(train)
        new_test = model1.transform(test)

    return new_train, new_test
```

Actually I want to calculate the selected features using the train dataset and then to apply it to the test dataset. It seems that the transform method cannot be aoolied in that case. What can I do in that case?

Comment: Have you tried after:  model1 = sel.fit_transform(train) to use somthing like:  model2 = sel.fit_transform(test) ?

Comment: Yes but this is not what I want. This technique keeps the features with variance greater that the proposed threshold. I want to keep those features from the train set and keep the same features to the test set.

Comment: Call directly new_train=sel.fit_transform(train) and new_test = sel.transform(test) after the first sel = VarianceThreshold(threshold=(0.00010 * (1 - .15))) This should work fine

Comment: `fit_transform` returns an array of changed dataset (`model1` in your case). And then you are using `model1.transform(train)`?? Are you sure your code is correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that there is a problem in the syntax you are using. See documentation and example [here](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.feature_selection.VarianceThreshold.html). The correct syntax is as follows:

```
def feature_selection_technique(train, test, lbls, technique):
   if technique == "variance":
        sel = VarianceThreshold(threshold=(0.00010 * (1 - .15)))
        new_train=sel.fit_transform(train)
        new_test = sel.transform(test)

    return new_train, new_test
```

That is, you should initialize `sel`, then fit it to the training data and transform it, and then transform the test data.

Comment: Yes this is working perfect. Thanks for the solution.